# Firebase Facebook login via mobile browser redirects/closes after 3 times pressing back button in Android

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, authentication, android-customtabs

I have implemented a Facebook login via firebase. On clicking the login button facebook opens the mobile browser in custom tabs. When I click the back or close button the redirection happens only after 3 times. The Facebook login page reloads 3 times and only then the page is getting closed.

Please find the code below,

```html
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.example.ondemand.R
import com.facebook.CallbackManager
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback
import com.facebook.FacebookException
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

class FirebaseFaceBookSignInActivity : Activity() {
    private var mCallbackManager: CallbackManager? = null
    private val TAG = "FacebookLogin"
    private var fbLoginButton: LoginButton? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        fbLoginButton = findViewById<LoginButton>(R.id.linearFBSignIn)

        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        LoginManager.getInstance()
            .registerCallback(mCallbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:$loginResult")
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel")
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error)
                }
            })

        fbLoginButton?.setOnClickListener {
            fbLogin()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        mCallbackManager?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    private fun fbLogin() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
            this,
            listOf("user_photos", "email", "public_profile", "user_posts")
        )
        LoginManager.getInstance()
            .logInWithPublishPermissions(this, listOf("publish_actions"))
    }
}
```

[image: custom tab facebook login]

Comment: Can you share the code which initiates Facebook login process.

Comment: Hi @VikasChoudhary, added the code